# deleting information in my table

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I've got my code I just want to delete an specific row but it will delete all when I run my program..?

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <?php
 $servername = "localhost"; 
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "csedb";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// sql to delete a record
$sql = "DELETE FROM addform WHERE id_stu=$id_stu";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
if($sql)
{
header('location:student.php');
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your where clause is only half there.

Comment: You have to give value to `id_stu` in your delete query.

Comment: SQL Query has a talking syntax, so if you read `DELETE FROM addform WHERE id_stu` does it not missing `= someid`? But i thing `DELETE FROM addform WHERE id_stu` should throw an syntax error in sql but it doesnt. Not so nice. Currently it will interpreted like: `DELETE FROM addform WHERE id_stu IS NOT NULL` or not empty

Comment: `WHERE id_stu` so keep going..........................

Comment: Real nice potential sql injection btw.

Comment: `if($sql)` that doesn't do much really.

Comment: and you're more than likely outputting before header also but you didn't check for errors on it.

Comment: and `$id_stu` as per your edit is defined where exactly? I feel this is going to take a while.

Comment: [*"I have my delete button where I don't have to put the value. – Kimboi 5 mins ago"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141962/deleting-information-in-my-table#comment73361617_43142056) - Errrr. what button?

Comment: never mind the button thanks

Comment: Problem solved then; great.

Comment: Your continuing silence or leaving the question isn't helping you, nor your cause. You've been given comments to answer to here, you haven't done that. You've been given answers but none seem to have been accepted or satisfied you in any way. If you cannot provide us with a minimal example or the errors you may have or the full code / db schema, then it will be up to you to figure out why it's not working for you. People are not mind readers, remember that.

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys.. It's already being solved :)

Answer (score 1):

give the value to where clause like

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM addform WHERE id_stu=<id_or_value>";
```

hope it helps

Comment: can you please share the table structure for my understanding

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a value for id_stu
DELETE FROM addform WHERE id_stu = your number

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a value:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM addform WHERE id_stu = 1";
```

Comment: I tried this also $sql = "DELETE FROM addform WHERE id_stu = id_stu"; I have my delete button where I don't have to put the value.

Comment: So you have to pass your target value to the delete query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass specific id of the row which you want to delete.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM addform WHERE id_stu=id_to_delete";
```

Also, don't forget to look about how to prevent sql injection.